# What are the facts and what is the truth?

Tags: ethics, philosophy-of-mind, truth, social-ethics

As I ask this know;
I purely ask this from a social point of view. As in conversations with others.
It's a random thought and kinda funny when I started thinking about it.

What's a fact?
Something believed and proven right.
What's the Truth?
Something believed to be what is right.

Why is it a fact can be the truth but the truth isn't always the fact?
Opinions

But on the same notion...the facts can be changed with the Truth?

The fact of the matter is...I believe it is the truth.

What are the facts and what is the truth?

Comment: A fact is just a true statement. Belief does not enter into it.

Comment: Think as in conversation with another. When things happen between all of us, we gather our truth. Each individuals truth, to the fact.

Comment: The idea that we each have our own truths is just fanciful wordplay. It has little to do with the process of rational inquiry.

Comment: I think you have the facts and I only have the truth.

Comment: Lol just kidding,sir. I can understand that view. It's just an abstract idea that I'm expressing. Hard to rationalize it.

Answer (score 0):

The term FACT expresses the idea that the claim MUST be TRUE and has already occurred from the time mentioned. Facts are permanent truths that with specific details can NEVER be false. If a person misused the word that does not change what it is.  If I call my car an apple that means I am using the Wrong term.  You can make a mistake.  You thought X was a fact and then something busts the idea to shreds.  You called X a fact incorrectly the same way a child can call a horse a dog.  The thing did not change in either case.
Truth is a category that often relates to the world around us.  Correspondence theory expresses that the things we sense are the ways of the world.  If I say "it is snowing" and you do not objectively observe snow at the location I refer to you would say the claim is false. If my claim objectively matches what you observe then the claim is said to be true.  Notice this example of truth does not stay true forever.  This is a contingent truth.  A truth that will alternate from truth to false at different times.  A Necessary truth can be by definition or rules alone such as a triangle has three sides or all bachelor's are single men. Some logical truths are called tautologies are true by definition.  Some truths like facts must be the case in the practical world such as all dogs are mammals or all women are human beings.  These truths do not tell you by definition they are so.  These you know from experience not definition.  Facts are these types of truth.

Comment: I purely meant in a social setting. As in occurrences in your life/others and how they are handled. I completely agree with what you are saying here. My question comes from a standing of self reflection on things that occur. Not so much sciences,nature, and mathematics.  If that makes sense